# Shared Projects list empty when adding reference in VS2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I am using `VS2019 Community Edition` and have created a `C# Console App` solution in one instance of `VS2019` and a `C#` Shared Project in another.

I have added a class to the Shared Project and then want to reference this shared project in the other project, so I right-click the References and choose to Add reference, then choose Shared Projects. The resulting window shows an empty list. Am I doing something wrong?

Other questions I have found suggest that the wrong Shared Project was created, i.e. using the wrong language, but I have checked and mine are indeed both `C#` projects.

The other suggested methods were to add it to the project manually by editing the `.csproj` file, which didn't work either, or something to do with `MS Build config` which is more than I want to get involved with.

Is it me or `VS2019`?

**UPDATE 1:**
So I managed to kind of fudge it, buy adding the `Shared Project` to the same project as the console project, but storing it in a different folder and reusing the `.sln` solution file to load it as a solution in `VS2019`. Progress, but even though I can add it as a reference, it doesn't seem to know about the classes in the `Shared Project`, even with a `using` reference.

Comment: Can you check what versions of .net framework each project is using? It might be that they are incompatible

Comment: @majita The console app is using 4.7.2 but I don't see anywhere to find the version the Shared Project is using...

Comment: ah wait its a shared project you are referring to, sorry it wont have a .net version in that case. I tried adding one in the same solution and then I can see and reference it but I also tried creating one in a different VS instance but I can't see it in that case either.